# Разъясните кое-что о блоках css?

Tags: html, css3

Как я понял по умолчанию ширина блока div равна доступной ширине родителя. А Высота div по умолчанию считается по содержимому. Скажите, а в этом случае пустые блоки накладываются типа друг на друга??

```
<div class ="class1">
     <div class = "class2"> </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если под "пустыми блоками" подразумеваются теги `<div>` без каких-либо заданных стилевых свойств (*border*, *padding*, *margin*), то такие пустые блоки схлопываются, не отображаются и имеют одинаковые начальные координаты и ширину родителя.

По сути, да, накладываются друг на друга.